# Losing selected value when user select another item inside another ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two `ListView` bound to two different properties. Basically those are two selectors (one for minutes and the other one for hours).

`ItemSource` is bound to a static `List<int>` and the `SelectedValue` to a property inside my model.

When I select one value from the hours list, it keeps its selected status... but when I choose the second value from the minutes list, it loses it, and vice versa.

I believe this is a graphical problem because both value are kept even if one value goes unselected.

**ListView call:**

```
        <ListView x:Name="listViewHoursSelect" ItemsSource="{Binding MaxHoursList}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMaxHours}" FontSize="{DynamicResource FontText}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{DynamicResource MainGray}" Style="{DynamicResource TimeSelectListView}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource TimeSelectItemsPanelTemplate}" Margin="0" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyle1}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

**ItemContainerStyle:**

```
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MainRed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource LightGray}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MainRed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MainRed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="{DynamicResource MainGray}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I restyled a lot of the `ListView`s and I even set all status (Normal, MouseOver, Selected, etc..).  I struggle to find why it keeps the selected value until I select another value in another list.

Let me know if you need some code, I didn't post anything yet because it's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, i was forgot to set SelectedUnfocused state :)

```
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MainRed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
```